# Applying Kmeans on 3D data with Scikit-learn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I have data (a numpy array **p**) with shape **(n,68,2)**. I am trying to apply k-means clustering to this data using Scikit-learn. I need to find **k** clusters from this data and the final output data after clustering should have dimensions of **(k,68,2)**.

When I provide **p** to the Kmeans function like

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=no_of_clusters, random_state=0).fit(p1)
```

it gives an Error

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

To get around this problem I had to separate the x and y coordinates to get **2** arrays of dimensions **(n,68)** and apply kmeans separately to them and combine the results later.

```
kmeans_y = KMeans(n_clusters=no_of_clusters, random_state=0).fit(p[:,:,1])
kmeans_x = KMeans(n_clusters=no_of_clusters, random_state=0).fit(p[:,:,0])
```

I would like to apply kmeans directly to the whole 2D coordinates without separating x and y and applying them separately. But I do need output data of dimensions **(k,68,2)** and not **(k,2)** which I got when i tried reshaping the array.

Comment: Please provide an excerpt of your "3d" dataset. If "3d" means three features per sample, your dataset can be represented by a matrix `(n,m)`, where `n` is the number of samples and `m` is the number of features.

Comment: one question, what is n? As in, what does it signify? Moreover, is 68 the number of data points? I get 2 is the number of dimensions each point has

Comment: You can reshape your data to be `(n, 136)`. The default distance is euclidean, it's worth thinking about if this makes sense in terms of your data, if not then you can write a custom distance metric.

Comment: @sentence The data is like (https://pastebin.com/HfAQJzKV)

Comment: @nickthefreak This is actually the data of position of landmark points for each image in a video. So each **image** has 68 points, with each point having 2 coordinates. **n** is the number of images in the video. I am trying to find **k** key images from these **n** images through clustering.

Comment: @DarkHorse1997, ok got it! as the others pointed out and i assumed in my answer, you can safely reshape your data

Answer (score 4):

sklearn KMeans fit() method expects X to have a 2d shape as shown in documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit):

```
X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
```

This means that you will have to reshape your np array to use the library. The new shape depends on what each dimension actually is (apologies, not perfectly clear from your question), but assuming `n` is the number of samples and `68,2` is the shape of the data points you can transform x in the following way:

```
x = x.reshape(n,68*2)
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments, you can also write your own distance method that would handle 3-d data, but it might be an overkill depending on the data needs.